# How does one customize measures/metrics in SonarQube Plugin Development?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube-plugin

I am developing a plugin for SonarQube 6.5 and want to do a little bit more with measures/metrics. My current domain looks like this:
[image: My Measure]
I would like to know how to add the fields on the left side of the measures domain like this:
[image: Coverage Measure]
It is not in the SonarQube Plugin Development Guide, or in any of their plugin examples.

I am also curious how to display more than one field on a file (when you click on a measure field, it brings you to a file tree):

[image: SonarQube Metric View]

Normally there is exactly one field displayed in this file view corresponding to one metric. As you can see, in my measure, I have fields for "high", "medium" and "low" security vulnerabilities and I would like to combine them so that they are all displayed on one file.